# How would I input data to a website text box, and then write that data to a text file?

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, ascii, urllib

I am writing a program that prints out ASCII art, based on a word that the user inputs. This word gets translated into an image link, and at this point, I am trying to send this link to https://www.ascii-art-generator.org/. This is not working. From here, I am trying to read the ASCII art generated, and then put it in a text file which I can print out. This is not working either. I am having trouble sending the link to the website and then retrieving that data. How would I achieve this with https://www.ascii-art-generator.org/?

```
import urllib
import requests
from googlesearch import search
import os
import sys
import time

os.system(["clear", "cls"][os.name == "nt"])

image = input("What do you want me to draw?\n\x1b[5m-\x1b[25m ")

query = image + " images"

print("\n\x1b[5mDrawing...\x1b[25m ", end="")

for image_link in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=1, pause=2): 
    print(image_link)

ascii_generator = "https://www.ascii-art-generator.org/"

website_data = {"name" : image_link, 
"type" : "text",
"id" : "fileupfield-url",
"class" : "width-input ff-inputfield"}

r = requests.post(ascii_generator, data = website_data)

with open("art.txt", "wb") as code:
    code.write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a making the right request, but with the wrong parameters and that post request leads you to another page, not the direct art. Even after you get to this page, it still takes a while for the art to load. The website is sending a request to check if the art is ready (which can be seen in Dev Tools). This process can be replicated in python easily, since the name of the image sent is stored on the website. You need beautifulsoup for this to work (`pip install bs4`)

## Code

```py
import requests, re, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ascii_generator = "https://www.ascii-art-generator.org/"
image_link = 'https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/2589fa711843a42405ae233b71f85ead362f6659/0_103_2160_1296/master/2160.jpg?width=300&quality=85&auto=format&fit=max&s=a52d11a9ace574f1927043f8f66a6032'

website_data = {
    'art_type': 'mono',
    'userfile': '(binary)',
    'userfile_url': image_link,
    'banner_text': '',
    'outFormat_caca': 'html',
    'figlet_font': 0,
    'width': 300,
    'banner_width': 100,
    'user_screen_width': 980,
}

r = requests.post(ascii_generator, data=website_data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
script = [script.text for script in soup.find_all('script') if 'var url' in script.text][0]

name = re.search(r"name=(\w*)", script).group(1)
now = int(time.time())

check_url = 'https://www.ascii-art-generator.org/FW/result.php'
params = {
    'name': name,
    'tscachebusttamp': now
}
check = '__wait__123'
while check == '__wait__123':
    check = requests.get(check_url, params=params).text
    time.sleep(3)
    print('checked')

check_soup = BeautifulSoup(check, 'html.parser')
art_link = 'https://www.ascii-art-generator.org' + check_soup.find('a', text='banner.txt')['href']
art = requests.get(art_link)
with open('art.txt', 'wb') as code:
    code.write(art.content)
    print('\nArt saved!')
```

Comment: This almost worked for me, but I am getting this error:            Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "artist.py", line 84, in <module>
    art_link = 'https://www.ascii-art-generator.org' + check_soup.find('a', text='banner.txt')['href']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable                 I am not sure why. Could you please explain why it is doing this? Sorry, I don't understand. Thanks!

Comment: The server could have been overloaded if you only tried it once. Did you change anything at all from the script? If no, try removing the `, text='banner.txt'`

Comment: I modified the script - and combined it with the original. I'll test it right now!

Comment: Can you print the variable check after the while loop and send the html in a pastebin? It works for me so I have no idea what’s going on unless I see the html that is failing.

Comment: Ok - I will include one. When it is just your code, it works - however, there are two areas on which it fails. When I change the color from "mono" to "color" it fails, and what has happened is that with different image URLs, it does not work. Here is the pastebin: https://pastebin.com/wjaHwfyg    Thank you for all of the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Here is the error message:                    checked
checked
checked
checked
checked
checked
checked
checked
checked
checked
checked
checked
checked
checked
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/**************/Desktop/Programming/Python Files/Artist/artist_test.py", line 44, in <module>
    art_link = 'https://www.ascii-art-generator.org' + check_soup.find('a', text='banner.txt')['href']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
[Finished in 47.8s with exit code 1]

Comment: On the website when color is selected, there seems to be another option for output. Which option do you want selected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202800/discussion-between-caspian-ahlberg-and-luckyzakary).

Comment: 400 width would be awesome, but it would be even better if the user could choose!